# Setting one combo box based on the value selected in another

Tags: silverlight-4.0

ComboBox Issues are back.

My application is in Silverlight with C#.Net code(VS2010). I have three ComboBoxes.

1. Country
2. State
3. City.

Now my requirement is when I select Country from my ComboBox(Ex:India) then all the states in India should be populated in State ComboBox and when I select some other country that countries states should be populated.For this I have created my Database in this manner only with giving UniqueID to each country.

My Database tables are designed this way

1. CountryTable(CountryId,CountryName)
2. StateTable(StateId,StateName,CountryId)
3. CityTable(CityId,CityName,StateName)

This way I have designed my DB.

I have coded in Service.svc.cs file to populate my Comboboxes.

Code in Service.svc.cs

```
[OperationContract]
        public List<GetCountry> GetCountryRecord()
        {
            using (Entities context = new Entities())
            {
                return (from c in context.CountryMaster
                        select new GetCountry
                        {
                            Country = c.CountryName,
                        }).ToList<GetCountry>();
            }
        }

 public class GetCountry
        {
            public string Country { get; set; }
        }
```

End of Service.svc.cs Code.

Code in the Form.Xaml.cs

```
var client = new ServiceReference1.AlumniServiceClient();
            client.GetCountryRecordCompleted += (s, ea) =>
                {
                   cboCountry.ItemsSource = ea.Result.Select(b => b.Country).ToList();;

                };
            client.GetCountryRecordAsync();
```

This is how im populating my combo boxes.
Now i want that the State values should change depending on the country selected and similarly the city combobox values should change depending on the state selected.

How can i achieve this by using this code and not recoding too many things.

Please guide wit code...

Comment: Please give your questions more meaningful titles.

Answer (score 0):

Either on the `SelectionChanged` event of the first `ComboBox` or when the bound setter gets called make the database call to populate the next `ComboxBox` in the sequence.

So initially you populate the country combo. Then when the user selects the country this sends the database request to populate the state combo. As this all happens asynchronously you're not tying up the UI while it happens.

Comment: No,actually i have tried different codes to work this out but no required result was achieved.Right now im only populating Data in country combo with the same code.As i mentioned i have coded for that in Service file.Now to achieve what im looking for where exactly should i code??and how??

Comment: @Ehtesham - Are you using MVVM with bindings or using the `SelectionChanged` event to update the selected country?

Comment: With the Page_Loaded event my country Combo is getting filled with All the Country Name available in my CountryMaster Table.
Now i want that the state combo values should change on the Country combo box SelectionChanged Event.
Like when the User Selects India from Country Combo than States in India should be populated in State Combo,when changes the selection to some other country then the respective states should be loaded.

Should i explain my DB structure or this is clear to understand???

Comment: @Ehtesham - that's not what I asked. How are you updated the selected country in your C# when the combobox selection changes? Post your XAML

Comment: Chris i have not Manually coded a word in XAML,whatever i have coded is in Service.svc.cs and Form.xaml.cs.The code i posted is the only code i have coded in my application to populate Countries.
Can u correct me if im following wrong procedure???

Comment: If im Using SelectionChanged event then what's next i should do to get my requirement done???

Comment: @Ehtesham - put the call to get the states into the handler for that event. Then the same for the cities. I can't say it any clearer than that.

Comment: Ok done with it.Would come back coz i have more queries related to same Application.

Comment: hi chris,
 [OperationContract]
        public List<GetState> GetStateRecord()
        {
            using (Entities context = new Entities())
            {
                return (from c in context.StateMasters
                        select new GetState
                        {
                            StateName = c.StateName,
                        }).ToList<GetState>();
            }
        }
this is my code to get Name of State from Database.

Comment: where should i filter the record???
Select State from StateMaster where CountryName="India"
This is what im asking